# Wordpress list child page content of current parent

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Using the below code I have successfully listed WordPress page titles. the pages have a **Featured Image**. when I run the below code the image shows up as the `Image Unavailable` one instead of the actual correct image.

Have I missed something out? The Title displays correctly.

**PHP**

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 30, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page'));

    while (have_posts()) { the_post();

        if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                <img src="/assets/dummy-image.jpg" alt="Image Unavailable" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
}?>
```

Comment: which wordpress version you using?

Comment: @VijayakumarSelvaraj Version 3.8.1

Comment: Does the image **dummy-image.jpg** exists? Is the path of **/assets/dummy-image.jpg** correct?

Comment: @kanenas.net no dummy-image.jpg does not, but a `Featured Image` does exist which doesn't show up when it should.

Comment: @Donald have you chosen your featured image from your computer, a gallery or "From URL"? Which theme do you use? Does your theme include `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in its **functions.php** file

Comment: @kanenas.net I am trying to get the 'Featured Image' of the page, this  has been uploaded and attached using WordPress so in the if statement above the if should be true and return the thumbnail.

Comment: @Donald **Note:** To enable featured images / post thumbnails, the current theme must include add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in its functions.php file.

Comment: @kanenas.net it is already added into functions.php as featured images work on other pages but this page I am using the `while` statement and its failing to work

Answer (score 0):

has_post_thumbnail() sometimes **fails** as codex says here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail

can you try the following

```
if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                <img src="/assets/dummy-image.jpg" alt="Image Unavailable" />
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: unforunately this only returns `<img src="/assets/dummy-image.jpg" alt="Image Unavailable" />` on my rendered page

Comment: did you tried to pass the post ID like this get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID; ?>

        <?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 20, 'post_parent' => $this_page_id, 'post_type' => 'page')); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>


                        <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($this_page_id, 'thumbnail') ); ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />

                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>


        <?php } ?>
```